# React.js - { loadingElement } не является функцией

Tags: javascript, reactjs

При запуске `yarn test` возникает множество ошибок, что функция `loadingElement`, ей не является `TypeError: loadingElement is not a function`.

Существует файл `minicart.js` в котором я определяю функцию `loadingElement`:

```
loadingElement = bool => {
    this.setState({
        isLoading: bool
    });
};
```

После чего, я передаю ее вниз: (классу `ProductList`)

```
get productList() {
    const { cart, removeItemFromCart } = this.props;

    const { cartCurrencyCode, cartId } = this;

    return cartId ? (
        <ProductList
            removeItemFromCart={removeItemFromCart}
            loadingElement={this.loadingElement} // Function loadingElement
            showEditPanel={this.showEditPanel}
            currencyCode={cartCurrencyCode}
            items={cart.details.items}
            totalsItems={cart.totals.items}
        />
    ) : null;
}
```

После чего, я ее принимаю в классе `product`, и пользуюсь следующим образом:

```
removeItem = () => {
    const { removeItemFromCart, loadingElement, item } = this.props;

    this.setState({
        isOpen: false
    });

    loadingElement(true);

    removeItemFromCart({
        item: item,
        loadingElement: loadingElement
    });
};
```

И на данном этапе `loadingElement(true);`, возникает одна из восьми ошибок `TypeError: loadingElement is not a function`.

**Желаемый результат**

1. Почему все работает, все функции выполняются, но `yarn test` говорит иначе?
2. Понять, и исправить все ошибки, которые происходят при запуске теста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А Вы в тесте передаете `loadingElement` props? Могу поспорить что нет.

Как решить?

Нужно во всех местах всегда делать проверки, именно для этого Вы и пишите тесты чтобы обнаруживать эти проблемы:

```
loadingElement && loadingElement(true);
```

Comment: Только начинаю изучать React, даже не мог подумать что именно в этом может быть ошибка! Благодарю Вас, проблема решена!

Comment: @Dmitry Удачи в изучении